# How to use subclasses of an abstract class in a normal class

Tags: java

I would like to ask a question about Abstract Classes in Java.

I have a class named as Car.
Also, I have created an Abstract class named as State. This abstract class has four subsclasses named are, GotoXY,Rest,Shake and Chase respectively.

A Car has a state and its state is changing randomly.
In the Car class I have created a variable as

```
private State state;
```

First Question : Should I create a constructor with State parameter in the Car Class?
Like:

```
Car(State _state){.//.}
```

**State Class :**

```
public abstract class State {

   public State chooseRandomState() {          
      return new GotoXY();
   }
   private void pickAnotherState(){
      //Random rnd = new Random();
      //currentState = States.values()[(int)(Math.random()*States.values().length)];
      //System.out.println(currentState);

   }

   public abstract String getCurrentStateName();
}
```

**Car Class is a normal class.**

I have instantiated the Car class in a Common Class.

Second Question: Should I create an enum in the State class and choose a random state?
How should I handle the Random state changes in the Car Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: Yes, you should code a constructor that receives any parameters needed to properly initialize the object's state (in this case, a `State` instance).

Second question: No, I wouldn't recommend an enum here. Look: Enums are aimed to produce a closed, finite number of objects known at compile-time. Interfaces, instead, may be extended by a number of implementations, not necessarily known at compile-time (at least, this was the original interface paradigm, before Java 15 introduced *sealing*).

I suggest you should keep your `Car` class absolutely independent of which and how many `State` implementations exist. How? Well, any random choice is based upon a numeric value (from 0 to 1) produced by `java.lang.math.Random`. So, you could instantiate every existing `State` implementation and store them into a `List` collection, and make `Car` index this list upon a random number (in the fashion your `pickAnotherState` method's commented code does it).

And, to keep `Car` and `State` instances completely independent, you'd better code a new class `StateManager` that contains static methods to create this list of States and publish it through a public getter for the `Car` class to use it.
In this way, whenever you code a new implementation of State, it will affect only the `StateManager`, not the client classes (like `Car`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I instantiate a List of State objects for each Car? 
Also, should I publish new State or use the existing one taken from the List when the state changes for the Car? @little-santi

Comment: You're welcome. If the subclasses of `State` do not have any instance variables, you can use all the time the same instances, and only one list.